# How to fix engine knock

Tags: mazda, noise

I drive a 1999 Mazda b3000 and I have what I believe to be an engine knock, I was wondering how to go about diagnosing this issue and how to fix it. Any help is super appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It really depends on what you mean by *knock*. It could be a low end rod bearing knock, or it might be pinging due to detonation. Could you be a little more specific with your question?

Comment: @Paulster2 it's a knocking coming from what sounds like a rod, it starts when I start the engine and continues and increases in intensity and speed as my rpms increase

Comment: Unless your confident enough to overhaul the engine. Replacing it with a used engine, would be the better option. Obviously this depends on whether it's actually rod knock or something like a collapsed lifter.

Comment: @Ben - or even an exhaust leak.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 A manifold leak would be a little higher pitched but I can see it being confused for something like lifter noise. OP needs to buy a stethoscope or a long screw driver he can use as one. One interesting trick I saw recently was to cut a gallon jug in half -think washer fluid- and fit it over the screw driver handle. It acts to amplify the noise and you don't need to stick your ear on the screw driver.

Comment: @Ben - That's pretty ghetto, but I likes it! :o)

Comment: do some searching there are quite a few similar posts. https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/27834/15036